# What were the state and federal regulations for OceanGate Inc., the ill-fated submersible charter company?

Tags: united-states, regulations

OceanGate Inc. is (or was) a US corporation based in the State of Washington, and everyone heard about the recent catastrophe of its submersible *Titan* while CEO and Founder Stockton Rush suffered the same imploding fate as the four other passengers.

OceanGate advertised itself as a submersible charter.

Does anybody here know the state or federal regulations that OceanGate needed to follow concerning the inspections of the submersible and its supporting surface vessel or platform?

Addendum: I found a fact from the State of Washington. Charter boat regulations apply to boats that "carry more than 6 passengers (or cargo) on state waters" (https://lni.wa.gov/licensing-permits/other-licenses-permits/charter-boats). I wonder if OceanGate evaded any inspection requirements because Titan carried a maximum of 5 people. But submersibles require a supporting vessel or platform, and I wonder what type of loopholes they jumped through before their implosion.

Comment: In case it helps, a quick Google search turned up:  https://www.dco.uscg.mil/Portals/9/DCO%20Documents/5p/5ps/NVIC/1993/n5-93.pdf

Comment: @MichaelHall I narrowed my question as follows: "Does anybody here know the state or federal regulations that OceanGate needed to follow concerning the inspections of the submersible and its supporting surface vessel or platform?"

Comment: I found a fact from the State of Washington. Charter boat regulations apply to boats that "carry more than 6 passengers (or cargo) on state waters" (https://lni.wa.gov/licensing-permits/other-licenses-permits/charter-boats). I wonder if OceanGate evaded any inspection requirements because Titan carried a maximum of 5 people while I imagine they started in state waters. But submersibles require a supporting vessel or platform, and I wonder what type of loopholes they jumped through before their implosion.

Comment: They surely did not start their voyage to the Titanic site in Washington state waters.  Did you have some other "start" in mind?

Comment: I know they were based in a port in Washington. I need to see if they stored Titan elsewhere,

Comment: I see they launched that trip from  St. John's Newfoundland, Canada. That certainly adds to the mix. And I remember hearing that Canada is also investigating, and now I know why.

Comment: It is something like a 12,000 km voyage from Washington State to the Titanic site by sea.

Comment: I believe OceanGate is still an "is", and will remain an "is" at least until the lawsuits pile up too high.

Comment: Not for the sub itself, but for the carrying vessel, e

Comment: There might also be laws covering the commercial transactions of selling seats on the subs.  It's possible for laws to regulate or even forbid selling those seats.